# How to make a property inside an object a type

Tags: typescript, types, typescript-types

> use typescript

I want to leave the `before type` below and define the `after type` separately.

```
type before = {
  title: string;
  sncFileInfoList: {
    sncFileKey1: string;
    sncFileKey2: string;
    sncFileKey3: string;
    sncFileKey4: string;
    sncFileNm: string;
  }[];
}
```

```
type after = {
  sncFileKey1: string;
  sncFileKey2: string;
  sncFileKey3: string;
  sncFileKey4: string;
  sncFileNm: string;
}
```

That is, I want to use the sncFileInfoList property of the `before type`.
The important thing is that the `before type` should stand still.
I've tried several Utility Types that I know of, but to no avail.
There is a way to disassemble the type and assemble it into an Intersection Type, but I think there will be a more elegant way.

Any help would be appreciated‍♂️

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Indexed Access Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) to look up a specific property on another type:

```
type before = {
  title: string;
  sncFileInfoList: {
    sncFileKey1: string;
    sncFileKey2: string;
    sncFileKey3: string;
    sncFileKey4: string;
    sncFileNm: string;
  }[];
}

type after = before['sncFileInfoList'][0]
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBARhBmB7ATtAvFA3gKClYAlsADYQBcUAzsMgQHYDmA3LlXQMYBiBpAknUgAyBahRx48lDt1IBpCCACMFarUYsJbLjwjyQAJhU16zVpOk69AZiNrTmqdrkKALLZMaJjmRAByAW3d1VgBfAG0AXRYQ7GxQSCgAQ3hgCGQoDDgkVDCAcm8dfiERYFyIsIAGCKA)